# How to serialize a list of POJO using FasterXML library

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml

I'm using FasterXML to serialize POJO. I want to serialize a list of my POJO. When serialize a signle POJO I get the expected xml (there's one problem --> question 2) Here's my code:

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
// add movies
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
xmlMapper.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS,
            MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS,
            MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS,
            MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS,
            MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS,
            MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS);
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(movies);
```

I get this:

```
<ArrayList>
    <item imdbID="tt0077687" title="The Hobbit" year="1977"/>
</ArrayList>
```

Here's what I want:

```
<movies>
    <movie imdbID="tt0077687" title="The Hobbit" year="1977"/>
    <movie imdbID="tt0077687" title="title2" year="1977"/>
</movies>
```

or

```
<movie imdbID="tt0077687" title="The Hobbit" year="1977"/>
<movie imdbID="tt0077687" title="title2" year="1977"/>
```

2. When I serialize a movie I get this:

Is it possible to get this:

```
<movie imdbID="tt0077687" title="The Hobbit" year="1977"><movie>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, do not try serializing `List`, `Map`s or arrays directly as the root-level value: always use a Bean (POJO). Properties may be of any types, recursively.

The problem is that Java type erasure make things problematic for collection and Map types in general (even with JSON); but there are additional problems for XML.

So while it may seem unnecessary, I have found it safest to have a simple Object as the root value, even if it's only something like:

```
public class Response {
   public List<Movie> movies;
}
```

Having said that, to change the name of root element can be done multiple ways. One possibility is to use Jackson annotation `@JsonRootName` (despite "Json" in there, it applies to all formats).

Or, you can use `ObjectWriter`, override root name with:

```
String xml mapper.writer().withRootName("movies").writeValueAsString(movies);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. What about my second question do you have an idea?

Comment: If you mean empty XML tags vs start/end element, that is possible by configuring underlying XML library (at least if you are using Woodstox). If you mean changing name of item element, it is trickier.

Comment: I just use FasterXML that Woodstox but I don't know how to configure it. I just added woodstox dependency to my pom.

Comment: Understood. What I meant is that you can construct `XmlMapper` with specific `XMLInputFactory` and/or `XMLOutputFactory` instances (these are Stax API abstractions, implemented by Woodstox with its `WstxInputFactory` and `WstxOutputFactory`) to use. And you can pre-configure said factories with different properties. But since I do not remember what output setting would work for forcing writing out of empty elements I guess it's moot point. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to annotate your `movies` variable. (And likely either pull it out into a field or declare an object to encapsulate it.) Check the annotations on this page to see if something matches. Sorry I can't be more specific.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

Comment: I don't a movie property. I have a Movie class