# JAX-RS change @XmlRootElement.name on runtime

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jaxb2

I have a DTO which cannot be modified, but it is required for use on a new endpoint. The problem is that the RootElement Name has to be changed, is there a way to to this on a specific endpoint ?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name = "wccevent")
public class SimpleWCCEvent {
..
}
```

On my new endpoint I need to change the root name from `wccevent` to `apiresponse`, is this possible ?

Something like

```
@GET
...
@XmlFeatures({overrideRootName = "apiresponse"})
public Response newEndpoint(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the need for the change int the DTO due to a broader change in the API? Maybe you might need to consider how you handle API changes in the greater schema of things.

Else have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288408/how-to-serialize-a-list-of-pojo-using-fasterxml-library?answertab=votes#tab-top) that suggests overriding the root element name as such:

```
String xml mapper.writer().withRootName("movies").writeValueAsString(movies);
```